# Are upvote-related badges a good idea?

Tags: discussion, badges, upvotes, electorate-badge

I suppose there is some problem related to the [Vox-populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) or [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badges. Perhaps there isn't, but this is my observation:

Today and last week I was checking PHP's questions, and with another refresh a few second later, I saw all of the questions had at least one upvote. And some of those questions were just really bad; not clear, no research and duplicates that were put on hold later ... and so on

I think those blind upvotes may have been cast just for one of those achievements. I'm also pretty sure that it's the same for other tags (not only for PHP).

The problem is : Given those upvotes, how we can show to new users what a useful and well researched question looks like? How can we encourage new users to research on Stack Overflow before asking if they just have to post a dumb question and hope to be upvoted plus with a duplicate.

I saw upvotes for posts in danger of SQL injection and sometimes for worse... what's next?

Edit :
I'd rather talk about questions here, because the quality of the question determine the minimal quality of answers (lot of answers are saying the obvious with poor quality questions).

I had an idea to limitate those blind upvotes :

- this functionnality should be deactivated during the first hours or two for non trusted users or new user's questions.
- During this time, if some(5 ?) reviewers or users flagged a question as too broad, duplicates or whatever, then this make sense to qualify a question as
  not good enought quality and then upvote is no more available

Comment: Welcome to reality. Even if we were to take away those badges, people will still upvote for things THEY find good, or for questions THEY also have. By far the majority of users on the site is not really interested in, or doesn't really know about, what we consider good quality content. I'd say that's more likely to be the real problem.

Comment: @Bart maybe we should consider making upvoting more difficult? *Click again after 5 seconds to make your upvote stick*. Down voting will be free ...

Comment: @rene [5 seconds to make an upvote stick?](http://i.imgur.com/UEvqZJD.jpg) ...

Comment: Didn't these upvotes come from one of the review queues? Or was that fixed since?

Comment: If a post with a single phrase with some comments in it asking for more infos are juste upvoted by the reviewers then we have a new problem

Comment: @Bart i'm agree with you, thanks for the dit btw. Yes this reality hurts me, because I can't admit that stack have a small piece of this community, that upvoting anything, anytime. Those badge deserves to be remove IMHO.

Comment: You can get both of those badges by only downvoting so they really encourage voting rather than upvoting.

Comment: Yeah but like me I prefer upvote or downvote  wisely and downvote only on some really bad question, not by pleasure. I prefer upvote to encourage an answer by the community when I can't answer myself... upvote anything, and expecially bad question is not a good idea, and should be moderate

Comment: Only letting downvotes sounds like a bad idea. Also just because a question is a duplicate doesn't mean it is a bad question especially if the duplicate is not easy to find.

Comment: letting downvote for 1 or 2 hours juste the time to determine if the question is not a bad one... after that upvote will be available again and will work as it works now

Comment: Removing the ability to upvote does not help as you still need the ability to provide positive feedback for users on new questions, not to mention that a question with a score of 0 is not considered a good question. Also how are you going to deal with the problem of good questions losing out on votes because the user can't upvote when they see the question and they won't go back later when the ability to upvote is unlocked. There is already a problem of people downvoting a question but never revisiting to to change the vote after it has been improved.

Answer (score 4):

Those badges are about encouraging voting with no preference towards up or down votes. Considering they have only been awarded 20k and 11.5k times I am not sure that they provide much motivation for  people upvoting questions.

The real issue here is that people like to upvote more then they like to downvote especially on answers since a downvote costs reputation but an upvote doesn't

Comment: Its only a token amount of reputation, and quite often you get it back anyways once the crap gets deleted. I never saw that as a deterrent, but I never understood why it was put in place at all.

Comment: @Polygnome while it may be a small amount it does matter to some people especially when they are near reputation boundary's

Comment: Down votes on questions are free! That's how I got my voting badges.

Comment: Downvotes aren't just free, they're also **hurtful**, @Laurel .